# Why does poll keep returning although there is no input?

Tags: c++, linux, file-descriptor, poll-syscall

I wrote a small test program to figure out how to talk to [`poll`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll). I created three files `testa`,`testb`,`testc` and wrote the string `hello\n` to the first. So, here is my invocation of `poll`:

```
poll(polls.data(),polls.size(),-1)
```

According to the manpage, a timeout of `-1` should indicate that the syscall never times out. However, it keeps returning without having anything to read. I always consume one byte of the input and can see the `hello\n` being printed, but poll doesn't stop there. It just keeps on pretending there to be something to read.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <sys/poll.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

typedef int fd_t;

int main() {
  fd_t const a = open("testa",O_RDONLY);
  fd_t const b = open("testb",O_WRONLY);
  fd_t const c = open("testc",O_RDWR);
  std::map<fd_t,std::string> names{{{a,"testa"},{b,"testb"},{c,"testc"}}};

  std::vector<pollfd> polls;
  polls.push_back(pollfd{a, POLLIN, 0});
  polls.push_back(pollfd{b, 0, 0});
  polls.push_back(pollfd{c, POLLIN, 0});

  while (poll(polls.data(),polls.size(),-1)) {
    for (auto p : polls) {
      if ((p.revents & (POLLIN|POLLERR)) == POLLIN) {
        std::cout << "{" << p.fd << ", " << p.events << ", " << p.revents << "} ";
        char byte;
        auto const rr = read(p.fd,&byte,1);
        auto const en = errno;
        if (rr) {
          std::cout << "File " << names[p.fd] << " says something: '" << ((int)byte) << " (" << (((' '<byte) && (byte<127))?byte:'\0') << ")" << "' \n";
        } else {
          std::cout << "Strange (file " << names[p.fd] << "). errno says " << en << "\n";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I get is this:

```
{3, 1, 1} File testa says something: '104 (h)' 
{5, 1, 1} Strange (file testc). errno says 0
{3, 1, 1} File testa says something: '101 (e)' 
{5, 1, 1} Strange (file testc). errno says 0
{3, 1, 1} File testa says something: '108 (l)' 
{5, 1, 1} Strange (file testc). errno says 0
{3, 1, 1} File testa says something: '108 (l)' 
{5, 1, 1} Strange (file testc). errno says 0
{3, 1, 1} File testa says something: '111 (o)' 
{5, 1, 1} Strange (file testc). errno says 0
{3, 1, 1} File testa says something: '10 ()' 
{5, 1, 1} Strange (file testc). errno says 0
{3, 1, 1} Strange (file testa). errno says 0
{5, 1, 1} Strange (file testc). errno says 0
{3, 1, 1} Strange (file testa). errno says 0
{5, 1, 1} Strange (file testc). errno says 0
{3, 1, 1} Strange (file testa). errno says 0
{5, 1, 1} Strange (file testc). errno says 0
{3, 1, 1} Strange (file testa). errno says 0
{5, 1, 1} Strange (file testc). errno says 0
```

(repeats the last two lines forever)

I'm building with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11    poll.cpp   -o poll` on the 3.10-2-amd64 kernel.

Comment: How do you expect to know when EOF appears else ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An EOF condition in a regular file is still readable.  In other words, your `read()` won't block.  Here's a nice list of how different implementations of `poll()` react to EOF in different sorts of file descriptors: http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/poll.html

Note that regular files always return POLLIN.  So you need to test for EOF separately.  In fact, poll on a regular file doesn't do anything for you.  You'll need sockets or pipes or something to test your code.

Other notes:  you probably want to check for other results in `.revents`.  POLLERR, POLLHUP, and POLLNVAL all signal different error conditions, and need special handling.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I expected EOF to be handled as if the file was blocked. I am trying the same with named pipes now (just one, actually (`testa`)) but now `poll` doesn't return at all, while `echo a > testa` does (when my program is running). Any idea?

Comment: Yes, that's the point.  `read()` from a named pipe will block until data is available.  `poll()` should not return at all until your named pipe is readable, which happens when you echo a character into it.

Comment: Yes, but this exactly doesn't happen. Even when I write data into the pipe, poll **doesn't** return. The `echo a >> testa` command returns (so I assume data was written to the pipe) but inside my program, poll doesn't return.

Comment: Works perfectly for me... I just used your code, commented out testb and testc, `mkfifo testa`, run the program, and `echo a >> testa`.  If your code is modified, post it.  Also show `ls -l test*`.

Answer (score 3):

Once you reach the end of a file, it remains readable so that `poll` will return immediately, and calling `read` will immediately return zero. You need to handle this condition, perhaps by closing it and removing it from the set of polls, where you're currently printing `Strange`.

Answer (score 2):

The local file descriptors are always ready to perform I/O (unlike sockets, because they are depend on the kernel internal buffer for I/O)). In your case file descriptors are always ready for reading, even if they are empty actually.